# how to check if variables is exist from arrays?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on my code to create the variables for the pixels.

I'm using the variables `pixel_start = 375`, `pixel_middle = 724` and `pixel_end = 1073` as I want to check each of them in each at a time.

When I try this:

```
def GoRight(self):
    basex, basey = self.getControl(347 + self.channels_Index).getPosition()
    basew = self.getControl(347 + self.channels_Index).getWidth()

    # change program controls to display the proper junks
    if self.channels_Index != len(self.program_buttons) - 1:
        CurrentRow = self.program_buttons[self.programs_Index].control.getX()
        CurrentWidth = self.program_buttons[self.programs_Index].control.getWidth()
        CurrentX = self.program_buttons[self.programs_Index].control.getX()
        print CurrentWidth
        #print CurrentX
        pixel_start = 375
        pixel_middle = 724
        pixel_end = 1073
        self.move_flag = True


        #Check on pixels size between start and end time
        if CurrentRow != pixel_end:
            if pixel_start == 375:
                if int(prog_width) == 2437:
                    programs_width = 2082
                    self.getControl(int(prog_id)).setWidth(int(programs_width))


                elif int(prog_width) == 2082:
                    programs_width = 1735
                    self.getControl(int(prog_id)).setWidth(int(programs_width))


                elif int(prog_width) == 1735:
                    programs_width = 1392
                    self.getControl(int(prog_id)).setWidth(int(programs_width))


                elif int(prog_width) == 1392:
                    programs_width = 1038
                    self.getControl(int(prog_id)).setWidth(int(programs_width))


                elif int(prog_width) == 1038:
                     programs_width = 691
                     self.getControl(int(prog_id)).setWidth(int(programs_width))


                     if int(prog_width) == 691:
                         self.programs_Index += 1
                    self.setFocus(self.program_buttons[self.programs_Index].control)


                 elif int(prog_width) == 691:
                      programs_width = 342
                      self.getControl(int(prog_id)).setWidth(int(programs_width))


                 elif int(prog_width) == 342:
                      self.getControl(int(prog_id)).setVisible(False)
                      self.getControl(int(prog_id)).setPosition(int(pos_X) - 350, int(pos_Y))


                 elif int(pos_X) == 724:
                     nextprogram = int(prog_id) + 1
                     self.getControl(int(nextprogram)).setPosition(1073, int(pos_Y))
                     self.getControl(int(nextprogram)).setVisible(True)


                     elif int(pos_X) == 1073:
                         self.move_flag = True
                         print "catch this one"



            if pixel_middle == 724:
                program_button = [elem.control for elem in self.program_buttons]
                programs_id = list()
                program_width = list()
                positions_X = list()
                positions_Y = list()

                for elem in program_button:
                    programs_id.append(elem.getId())
                    positions_X.append(elem.getX())
                    positions_Y.append(elem.getY())
                    program_width.append(elem.getWidth())
                 programs_id = map(str, programs_id)
                 posX = map(str, positions_X)
                 posY = map(str, positions_Y)
                 program_width = map(str, program_width)

                 for pos_X, pos_Y, prog_id, prog_width in zip(positions_X, positions_Y, programs_id, program_width):
                     if int(pos_X) == 724:
                         self.getControl(int(prog_id)).setPosition(375, int(pos_Y))


                     if self.move_flag == True:
                         print "catch this two"
                         if pixel_end == 1073:
                             program_button = [elem.control for elem in self.program_buttons]
                         programs_id = list()
                         program_width = list()
                         positions_X = list()
                         positions_Y = list()

                         for elem in program_button:
                             programs_id.append(elem.getId())
                             positions_X.append(elem.getX())
                             positions_Y.append(elem.getY())
                             program_width.append(elem.getWidth())
                         programs_id = map(str, programs_id)
                         posX = map(str, positions_X)
                         posY = map(str, positions_Y)
                         program_width = map(str, program_width)

                         for pos_X, pos_Y, prog_id, prog_width in zip(positions_X, positions_Y, programs_id, program_width):
                             if int(pos_X) == 1073:
                                 print "catch this three"
                                 self.getControl(int(prog_id)).setPosition(724, int(pos_Y))


                    self.channels_row += 1
                    #print self.channels_row
                    if self.channels_row <= 7:
                         pass
                         #self.move_flag = False
             self.move_flag = False
```

It will loops on the code as it will firing twice.

in `pixel_middle`, you can see that I'm using this:

```
for pos_X, pos_Y, prog_id, prog_width in zip(positions_X, positions_Y, programs_id, program_width):
    if int(pos_X) == 724:
        self.getControl(int(prog_id)).setPosition(375, int(pos_Y))
```

in `pixel_end` bottom line:

```
if self.move_flag == True:
    print "catch this two"
    if pixel_end == 1073:
        ...
        for pos_X, pos_Y, prog_id, prog_width in zip(positions_X, positions_Y, programs_id, program_width):
            if int(pos_X) == 1073:
                self.getControl(int(prog_id)).setPosition(724, int(pos_Y))
```

I'm trying to check if the pixels in the arrays for the `pos_X` does exist and if they do not exist then move to the next variable, e.g move from `pixel_middle` and use `pixel_end` instead. I tried to block the code from firing twice when I try to use `if self.move_flag == True`, but it did not help.

I'm using the arrays for the `pos_X` to check that if the pixels value `375`, `724` does exist in the arrays.

Can you please show me an example of how I can use to check that if the pixels in the arrays do exist and if they don't exist using with `pixel_middle` and `pixel_end` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very clear what are you exactly trying to. But if want to check if a value exists in an array, then following check will do:

if value in array:
   ....

```
x = [ 1, 2, 100]
if 2 in x:
   print '2 is there'
```

Comment: I'm using the variables `pixel_start`, `pixel_middle` and `pixel_end` to get the other code seperate. As you can see that I'm using the variable `pos_X` to check that if the pixels value 375, 724 in the arraus does exist. My trouble is with `pixel_middle` and `pixel_end`, because both code will firing twice when I'm trying to use them once at a time where you can see what I have post in my question on above with `in pixel_middle, you can see that I'm using this:` and `in pixel_end bottom line:`

Comment: Can you please show me how I can stop the code from firing twice when I'm using `pixel_middle` and `pixel_end` at the same time when I'm checking for the pos_X that if I have the value 1073?

Comment: It would have helped if you pasted a run-able example. I believe GoRight is a method in a class. But anyway, the block starting with "if CurrentRow != pixel_end:" will always set self.move_flag to False. May be that'll give you clue.